# Resetting VNC account through SSH?

Tags: vnc

In order to perform some remote operations on my normally headless-with-desktop-over-LAN Pi2, I signed up for a trial account at the raspi's default VNC cloud service. Now, with the trial having expired, cloud connections don't work, which is expected. Less expected is that the Pi now refuses all VNC connections, even those made directly over LAN, with a "Subscription expired" message.

Seeing as an unregistered, account-less VNC copy does accept LAN connections, I would like to somehow purge that account information, but I'm limited to doing so through SSH. I've tried basic operations like `apt-get --purge`ing some relevant packages and reinstalling, without success.

Likely solutions would include knowing in what directory the VNC service stores its account credentials, an alternative remote GUI where I can interact with VNC's windowed interface, or knowing a full list of VNC-related packages that might need `--purge`ing, since information about the latter is remarkably scarce.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the /root/.vnc/config.d directory should do it, then restart the vnc server and you should be back to the default free mode which will allow tcp connections.